# Ansible: Setting enviroment variables (PATH, GOPATH, etc.) in a generic way (centos, ubuntu, etc.)

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, centos

What is the recommended clean idempotent way (good practice) to add/modify persistent environment variables in Ansible?

For instance, what is the recommended way to add a directory to the PATH? Or setting GOPATH/GOBIN?

Ideally it should work well for Centos, Ubuntu and other common Linux distributions.

**Update** Just to clarify. I know how to pass environment variables to tasks/roles. But this is not what I want/need. After provisioning, I want a different PATH, GOBIN, GOPATH, etc.
I also know I could hack/edit .profile, .bashrc
But I am looking for a clean recommended best practice.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is, you do not use evironment variables for this. If you need a variable for all ansible tasks on every host, then you could use  the file `group_vars/all.yml` .

Variables declared in this file will be applied to the default group `all`. This group contains all hosts.
 It has no dependency to any distribution.

Comment: no, this is not what I need. Actually I want to explicitly set things up in the host. Configure GOPATH, etc. They need to be persisted.